# iOS: Not full frame of UICollectionViewCell is tappable/clickable

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell

I created a `UIView` with a `UICollectionView`, and that `UIView` is added on a `UIViewController`. `UIViewController` using the delegate (`photoDidTapped`) of that `UIView` to determine is something was clicked/tapped. First row, is okay, means whole cell area is tappable. Second row, horizontal half of that is clickable. 3rd row, almost 10% horizontal of the cell is clickable and so on.

Code:

```
- (UICollectionView *)collectionView
{

    if (!_collectionView) {
        UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
        flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(THUMB_DIMENSION, THUMB_DIMENSION);
        [flowLayout setMinimumInteritemSpacing:0.0f];
        [flowLayout setMinimumLineSpacing:PHOTO_MARGIN];

        _collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
        _collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, self.frame.size.height);
        _collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        _collectionView.delegate = self;
        _collectionView.dataSource = self;
        _collectionView.allowsSelection = YES;
        _collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;
        _collectionView.scrollEnabled = NO;

        [_collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];


    }

    return _collectionView;
}


- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return (_photos.count > 9 ? 9 : _photos.count);
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath; {

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];

    imgView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    imgView.backgroundColor  = RGB(250, 250, 250);


    if (_photos.count) {
        PhotoDM *photo = [_photos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [imgView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:photo.largeLink]
                placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];
    }

    [cell addSubview:imgView];
    return cell;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"tapped: %ld", (long)indexPath.row);

    if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(photoDidTapped:)])
        [delegate performSelector:@selector(photoDidTapped:) withObject:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:indexPath.row] ];
}
```

Comment: Why are you using SCREEN_WIDTH macros? You can use self.bounds.size.width.

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains 2 problems.
1. If you create a subview, you should use [self.bounds](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/bounds).
2. The view can be resized, after UICollectionView has been added. It means that you should configure [autoresizingMask](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/autoresizingMask) or [NSLayoutConstrans](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html). (UICollectionView can be out of view's bounds).

To debug this problem, you can create different background colors for the view, the collectionView, the viewController's view.